# django translate text inside html tags and maintain html tags

Tags: django

I've found a tool I can use to translate text `googletrans`

this is how it works

```
from googletrans import Translator

translator = Translator()
result = translator.translate(text, dest=lang)

print(result.text)
```

but in the case that my text might come from `django-ckeditor` so it includes html tags for example

```
<h1>Some Title</h1>
<p>Some Text</p>
```

I need to pass this text to it and still maintain the html tags, so far it tends to break that symetry and the text formatting gets ruined to mention it fails to translate correctly.

There's tools like `beautiful soup` that can help you read html text, that direction looks like it's going to be bloated code that "barely" works, I'm curious if someone knows of a way to get it to work more cleanly.